# How to get coordinates for lighting from moving object? WebGL

Tags: matrix, vector, webgl

I have an object. It moves around:

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [ 0.0, 0.0, -68.0]); // far
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(sunBlueAngle), [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]); // angle
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [25, 0, 0]); // offset center
```

And now I want to use it as source of light. I need to pass to vertex shader location of my light.

```
uniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;
```

But I don't know this coordinates, since my object always moves.
How to get this coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally get the world position of an object by getting elements 12, 13, 14 of your matrix

```
var worldPosition = [
  mvMatrix[12],
  mvMatrix[13],
  mvMatrix[14],
];
```

or this should also work in most modern browsers

```
var worldPostion = mvMatrix.slice(12, 15);
```

If you're using glMatrix then you can also do

```
var worldPosition = vec3.create();
mat4.getTranslation(worldPosition, mvMatrix);
```